# kubectl connection failure while port-forwad

Tags: eclipse, kubernetes, azure-aks, remote-debugging, portforwarding

getting below error after trying to connect forwarded port

IPv4: dial tcp4 127.0.0.1:8000: connect: connection refused IPv6 dial tcp6: address localhost: no suitable address found
error: lost connection to pod

command used to forward port:

kubectl port-forward --address 127.0.0.1 pods/pod-name 9000:8000 -n namespace

I am trying to connect from eclipse over this port using remote debugging.

I am expecting to get connected on this port from eclipse.

Comment: Check your arguments; 8000 would be the port inside the pod and not on localhost, wouldn't it?

Comment: Can you remove `--address` parameter and test again ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but it does works pointing to a service.

So, this fails:

```
➜ kubectl port-forward argocd-server-557c4c6dff-wgbb5 8888:80
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8888 -> 80
Forwarding from [::1]:8888 -> 80
Handling connection for 8888
E0201 17:52:57.490441  977246 portforward.go:409] an error occurred forwarding 8888 -> 80: error forwarding port 80 to pod 0fed3a0162db39c0d4bfd1a3b1bbd02ae372cd983860ab76a64f60d8b94bc8c5, uid : failed to execute portforward in network namespace "/var/run/netns/cni-04914fb3-589e-ab88-e11b-9c8555cf4dac": failed to connect to localhost:80 inside namespace "0fed3a0162db39c0d4bfd1a3b1bbd02ae372cd983860ab76a64f60d8b94bc8c5", IPv4: dial tcp4 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused IPv6 dial tcp6: address localhost: no suitable address found
error: lost connection to pod
```

But this works:

```
➜ kubectl port-forward svc/argocd-server 8888:80
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8888 -> 8080
Forwarding from [::1]:8888 -> 8080
Handling connection for 8888
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message, when the pod I was connecting to, was not up and running.

```
IPv4: dial tcp4 127.0.0.1:8000: connect: connection refused IPv6 dial tcp6: address localhost: no suitable address found error: lost connection to pod
```

Turns out, the error message that indicated an ipv6 issue was missleading.

Get the status of your pod like this:

```
kubectl -n <namespace> get pods <pod-name>
```

Make sure the pod is in status RUNNING

```
NAME                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
mypod                           1/1     Running   0          15m
```